# In pandas: Interpolate between two rows such that the sum of interpolated values + second row = old value of the second row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I found it really hard to articulate this problem, but it is a similar problem to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70305143/in-pandas-interpolate-between-two-rows-such-that-the-sum-of-interpolated-values).

For example, let's say I have a table like this:

| Label | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | Nan |
| D | Nan |
| E | Nan |
| F | 12 |

It needs to look like this:

| Label | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 3 |
| E | 3 |
| F | 3 |

Used the next available value (12) and divided it by the number of Nan values + 1 (12/4) = 3 and replaced the Nan values AND the original value used to interpolate(12) by 3. It is similar to the previous question but also modifies the original value used for interpolation.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'Label': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F','G','H','I'],
                     'Value': [1, 2, None, None, None, 12,None,None,4]})

test['break'] = np.where(test['Value'].notnull(),1,0)
test['group'] = test['break'].shift().fillna(0).cumsum()
test['Value2'] = test.groupby('group').Value.apply(lambda x: x.fillna( x.max() / len(x)))

for row in range(0,test.shape[0]):
    if test['break'].iloc[row] == 0 and test['break'].iloc[row+1] == 1:
        test.at[row+1, 'Value2'] = test['Value2'].iloc[row]
```

df.interpolate() is not capable of doing this, and this is what I have so far. It gets the job done, but is not very elegant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```py
test = pd.DataFrame({'Label': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F','G','H','I'],
                     'Value': [1, 2, None, None, None, 12,None,None,4]})

tr = test.assign(
    g=(~test['Value'].isna())[::-1].cumsum()
).groupby('g')['Value'].transform

df = test.assign(Value=tr('last') / tr('size'))

>>> df
  Label     Value
0     A  1.000000
1     B  2.000000
2     C  3.000000
3     D  3.000000
4     E  3.000000
5     F  3.000000
6     G  1.333333
7     H  1.333333
8     I  1.333333
```

##### Explanation

With the `.assign(g=...)` we make groups of values that end with a non-NaN values and preceded by zero or more NaN:

```py
>>> test.assign(
...     g=(~test['Value'].isna())[::-1].cumsum()
... )

  Label  Value  g
0     A    1.0  4
1     B    2.0  3
2     C    NaN  2
3     D    NaN  2
4     E    NaN  2
5     F   12.0  2
6     G    NaN  1
7     H    NaN  1
8     I    4.0  1
```

Then, we use `.groupby('g')['Values'].transform` twice: to get the `last()` value, and to divide it by the `size()` of the group.

Comment: A far more elegant way than I could ever have managed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In the similar vain as the very good answer by [Pierre D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758174/pierre-d), you could also use the following solution for the purpose of grouping in one go:

```
test['Value'] = ((test.assign(id = (~test['Value'].isna()).cumsum().mask(test['Value'].isna())
                              .bfill()))
 .groupby('id').transform(lambda x: x.bfill() / len(x)))

  Label     Value
0     A  1.000000
1     B  2.000000
2     C  3.000000
3     D  3.000000
4     E  3.000000
5     F  3.000000
6     G  1.333333
7     H  1.333333
8     I  1.333333
```